# Best way to store multiple sets in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, set

I have multiple sets (of coordinates) that I would like to store into one main list/dictionary/array. I am not sure how to go about this...

This is my objective:
Use a for-each loop from the main list, to intersection each list and compare them to one another

Example:

```
a = {'[2, 2]', '[2, 10]', '[3, 6]', '[4, 5]'}

b = {'[3, 6]', '[6, 6]', '[9, 1]', '[9, 8]'}

c = {'[2, 2]', '[6, 7]', '[7, 5]', '[9, 2]'}

d = {'[1, 2]', '[2, 2]', '[3, 6]', '[7, 5]'}


list1 = [a, b]

list2 = [c, d]


for each set1 in list1:

   for each set2 in list2:

      set1.intersection(set2)
```

Comment: You appear to be storing your coordinates as strings. That's an extremely awkward, hard-to-use data representation. I suspect this was an attempt to fix a TypeError that you got when you tried to store lists in a set. You should use tuples, not strings.

Comment: Do you also want to compare set a to set b? or only a to c, a to d, b to c en b to d?

Comment: @joostblack just looking to compare a to c,d/ b to c,d/ c to a,b/ d to a,b.

Comment: I used strings because I wasn't sure how else to get the intersection between the two sets. I did originally want them as tuples but the intersection method is only provided for tuples. Sorry, this is the first time I've used stack overflow. I hope you see this comment.

Comment: @BrookeForster @ the person like I did to you, if you want to be sure they get it.

Answer (score 0):

First the easiest way. That is by using tuples like the comments suggested:

```
# your sets
a = {(2, 2), (2, 10), (3, 6), (4, 5)}
b = {(3, 6), (6, 6), (9, 1), (9, 8)}
c = {(2, 2), (6, 7), (7, 5), (9, 2)}
d = {(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 6), (7, 5)}

#print output
print("Compare a to c+d:",a&(c|d))
print("Compare b to c+d:",b&(c|d))
print("Compare c to a+b:",c&(a|b))
print("Compare d to a+b:",d&(a|b))
```

output:

```
Compare a to c+d: {(3, 6), (2, 2)}
Compare b to c+d: {(3, 6)}
Compare c to a+b: {(2, 2)}
Compare d to a+b: {(3, 6), (2, 2)}
```

If your input is however like described in your example I would do something like this:

```
class Coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    @staticmethod
    def from_string(coord_str):
        x,y = coord_str.strip("[]").split(",")
        return Coord(int(x),int(y))


    @staticmethod
    def convert(my_iter):
        return set(map(Coord.from_string, my_iter))


    def __eq__(self, other): 
        if not isinstance(other, Coord):
            return False
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Coord(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)


    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__repr__())

# your sets
a = {'[2, 2]', '[2, 10]', '[3, 6]', '[4, 5]'}
b = {'[3, 6]', '[6, 6]', '[9, 1]', '[9, 8]'}
c = {'[2, 2]', '[6, 7]', '[7, 5]', '[9, 2]'}
d = {'[1, 2]', '[2, 2]', '[3, 6]', '[7, 5]'}

# creating sets
set_a = Coord.convert(a)
set_b = Coord.convert(b)
set_c = Coord.convert(c)
set_d = Coord.convert(d)
set_a_and_b = Coord.convert(a)|Coord.convert(b)
set_c_and_d = Coord.convert(c)|Coord.convert(d)

# print requested information
print("Compare a to c+d:",set_a.intersection(set_c_and_d))
print("Compare b to c+d:",set_b.intersection(set_c_and_d))
print("Compare c to a+b:",set_c.intersection(set_a_and_b))
print("Compare d to a+b:",set_d.intersection(set_a_and_b))
```

output:

```
Compare a to c+d {Coord(2, 2), Coord(3, 6)}
Compare b to c+d {Coord(3, 6)}
Compare c to a+b {Coord(2, 2)}
Compare d to a+b {Coord(2, 2), Coord(3, 6)}
```